# Парсинг TP-Link

Tags: java, парсер, роутер

Здравствуйте.
Хотел бы сделать такую штуку:
Есть страничка роутера с адресом 192.168.0.1, меня интересует написание программы на джаве для изменения "**Тип подключения WAN**". Не знаю с какой стороны подойти к решению данной проблемы.
Надо чтобы программа **заходила на сайт**, дальше **авторизировалась** на той страничке потому что надо вводить логин и пароль, дальше **находила нужный пункт** и **изменяла в нем данные**.

Буду очень благодарен если поможете.

Comment: А ssh, telnet поддерживает роутер?

Comment: @Vladimir чесно сказать не разбираюсь в этом, немного погуглил, но так и не узнал есть ли у моего роутера поддержка тех функций. Роутер кстати Tp-link wr720n. Но всё таки средствами программирования нельзя такое сделать? телнет и ssh это вроде немного другое как мне показалось.